# Command to list vdev device names for a ZFS pool for scripting?

Tags: linux, zfs

I'm working on a script that requires the device name of the disks in all of the vdevs for an arbitrary pool. (All of the devices in the vdevs in my pools are disks.)

`zpool list -v mypoolname` seems to mostly be what I want:

```
$ zpool list -v mypoolname
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
mypoolname   100G   90G  10.0G    90%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
  mirror   100G   90G  10.0G         -
    devicename1      -      -      -         -
    devicename2      -      -      -         -
```

But the only obvious way to determine which lines of the output are the disks is to check for four spaces at the start of the line.

Is there a better, script-safe command I could run instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
zpool list -v -H -P
```

---

```
-v verbose
-P show full paths, not just the last component
-H script mode - no headings, fields separated by tab character
```

That will get you a lot closer.

Comment: My `zpool` doesn't have a `-P` option for `list`. I see `... module v0.6.3-5~trusty, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5` via `dmesg | grep ZFS`.

Comment: ah, my version on trusty is `module v0.6.5.11-1~trusty, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5`  The line from my sources.list.d file for zfs is `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/zfs-native/stable/ubuntu trusty main`